# How to we assign a variable derived from the keyword section to a variable in variable section in robot framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to load the json file and get the credential in the keyword section.
I need to pass the value of that variable to the variable section , so that I can use them as the arguments that can be passed while importing a python file.

eg for abc.py file

```
class abc():

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
```

robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library.   abc.py   ${username}   ${password} as pyhton_file
*** variables ***
${username}
${password}

*** keywords ***
    get credentials from json file
        ${json_file}=    Get File        example.json
        ${json_obj}=     Evaluate        json.loads('''${json_file}''')      json
        ${username}=     Set Variable    ${json_obj['username']}
        ${password}=     Set Variable    ${json_obj['password']}
        Set Global Variable     ${username}
        Set Global Variable     ${password}
```

please let me know how can I pass the username and password value that is derived from keyword section as argument while creating the object

Comment: You could move the `Get File` and the username and password fetching into the constructor of your library, and pass the JSON file name as an argument to the library.

Comment: Thanks @bence but how is that done. New to Robot framework

Comment: You did it already in your keyword, do the same in Python. Open the file, load as JSON, access the needed attribute. In Python, in your constructor.